# Schengen Visa- chances for a student?

Tags: visas, schengen

Obviously no one can say whether I will or will not get the visa but would appreciate some inputs. I know it is generally difficult for non-employed people to get a Schengen visa. What do you think about my case?

I'm an Indian citizen, studying in university in the US, and want to go for a solo, short trip to France/Italy. My dad, who works in a big MNC in India, will help finance the trip. I have previously travelled to Schengen zone on family and school trips, no visa overstay or visa denial for any country previously. I have a valid US study visa.

Obviously being a student I don't have a job nor do I own property. I love travelling and want to make use of time during holidays in college. 
What can I do to strengthen my case? I plan to apply at the French consulate in Miami.

I started university this August and will graduate in May 2019. So I am travelling at the end of my first year here (summer 2016), would go home to India after a 10-ish day trip and then return to college at the beginning of the next academic year (Aug 2016).

Comment: You will depart France to continue your studies, right? So you should demonstrate that you will return to university.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are *halfway* through some part of your studies, and that you can document that fact. That makes you look less like a would-be immigrant, which is always a concern.

Answer (score 3):

I applied for Schengen Visa for a couple times while I was a student in the UK as well. I got visa every time. Just make sure you provide all the documents and enough fund. If you have every thing they need to see; return tickets, money in the bank to support while you're there and letter from your university and accommodation. I don't see why your case would be different than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think getting schengen visa is easier if u are a full time student, no? It doesn't look like there is any problem with your background so i think you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

As a student in an US university that needs to apply for a schengen visa, as long as you are able to provide the necessary documents, they usually just give you the visa. You shouldn't worry, honestly. Another plus is that the French usually are more generous with their visa allotments, so I say that you shouldn't worry!